# Which sparql query will return the size of an owl ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I am trying to to take some metrics on an owl ontology for example the Size of an ontology.

Size refers to the number of entities in a module, |M|. This can be further
subdivided into class size |C|, object property size |OP|, data property size
|DP|, and individual size |I|.

```
Size(M) = |M| = |C| + |OP| + |DP| + |I|
```

Is there a sparql query that can return the size of the ontology? Thanks

Comment: sure, `select (count(?entity) as ?cnt) where { ... }` - indeed inside the brackets you have to select the triples with the entities. For OWL you might find all classes if you look for `rdf:type` being `owl:Class`

Comment: hello and thnx for your reply!i am a newbie in sparql and i know it must be something like this                   
select (count(?entity) as ?cnt) where { 
?entity a owl:Class.
?entity a owl:ObjectProperty
}           but it doesnt work :(

Comment: of course it doesn't - multiple triple patterns denote the intersection, so your query does ask for entities being class and property at the same time.

Comment: you can use `select ?type (count(?entity) as ?cnt) { VALUES ?type { owl:Class owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty} ?entity a ?type } GROUP BY ?type`

Comment: thnx for our reply.you are right my queery was wrong. i tried your queery but it doesnt work ether. i use this site to ask my queries http://139.91.210.25:8890/sparql and i give Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI) the pizza ontology :http://localhost:8890/pizza maybe there is something wrong with the ontology :(

Comment: this endpoint is working with a quite old version of a triple store which doesn't support SPARQL 1.1 which is necessary for `VALUES` keyword you have to use something else like `UNION` here